# CSS Formatting of List Element has improper margin

Tags: html, css

When I have an unordered list formatted as inline-blocks, the last list element in the list appears to have extra top margin if the other elements have any block content. Take a look at this HTML:

```
<div id="report_builder">
    <ul id="report_layout_1" class="report_layout ui-droppable">
        <li rel="recid">Id
            <div><input type="text" class="report-column-value"></div>
        </li>
        <li rel="street1">Address
            <div><input type="text" class="report-column-value"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            Last Field
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#report_builder li {
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#report_builder > ul {
    float: left;
}

.report_layout {
    height: 150px;
}
.report_layout > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.report_layout > li:last {
    cursor: default;
}
.report_layout > li a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.report_layout > li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#eee;
}

#report_builder input.report-column-value {
    width: 95px;
}
```

​
Why does that last list element drop down? Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TS4fZ/) to demo what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is weird, but you should force your list items to align to the top using `vertical-align: top;`. See [working version on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TS4fZ/10/).

That's because `inline-block` elements will align as `inline`, i.e., siblings will use the baseline as the alignment reference.

Comment: This is the correct answer. add `vertical-align:top;` to `.report_layout > li`

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Elements with inline-block set on them render with a 4 pixel margin to the right.

See [this](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/).

It is an issue with the white space between the <li> elements. If you remove the white space, the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I apologize - I answered the question before looking at your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `li` float left and display: inline. They are lined up in your jsfiddle then.

http://jsfiddle.net/eHmtR/1/